# Can't get PipeReader.TryRead to work when reading from a socket

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I'm trying to convert some old C# socket code over to use the newer PipeReader library.

I have a thread that connects to a remote m/c via a socket and reads (forever) and processes any data the remote endpoint is sending. I wanted to see how much of a memory/performance boost I'd get converting it over to PipeReader and stackallocated buffers. I have something like this:

```cs
// setup the connection to the remote endpoint
// and start the data flow
using var connection = new TcpClient(_connectionInfo.Name, _connectionInfo.Port) {
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Milliseconds,
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Milliseconds,
};
...
// now attach a pipereader to the end of the socket to suck the data out
var reader = PipeReader.Create(connection.GetStream(), new StreamPipeReaderOptions(bufferSize: BufferSize));
while (!_stopToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
  if (reader.TryRead(out ReadResult result)) {
    ...
    ...
    reader.AdvanceTo(result.Buffer.End);
  }else {
      _stopToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  }
}
```

`TryRead` never succeeds - it always returns `false`. If I look at the remote component that's being connected to logs, then I can see "time out on select" error being logged against my IP address, which i guess indicates there's nothing listening on my end?

The curious thing though is if I use `ReadAsync` instead then everything works ok!

I have no problem using the async way of doing things - I'm already in a thread, so don't need it - but I'm curious to know what it is I'm missing.

Comment: Note that `TryRead` returns immediately if no data is available (yet). Then you are waiting 5 seconds before next attempt, which might be the reason. `ReadAsync` on the other hand will wait until data is available, then read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `TryRead` implementation of `StreamPipeReader` as created by your `PipeReader.Create(connection.GetStream())` call is *not* a synchronous counterpart to `ReadAsync` - you have to call `ReadAsync` first before `TryRead` will ever return data fetched by it. Endlessly looping over `TryRead` will *not* work. There is [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30161) about the confusion caused by this.

The **recommended solution** is to rewrite your code to be `async` and qualify for `ReadAsync` since pipelines are designed to be used async.

---

The other solution to at least get synchronous reads is using the [Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial](https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/) NuGet package which implements `SocketConnection`s over `Socket`s without the need for `Stream`s. Its pipe just so happens to have an implementation of `TryRead` which works as expected. Your code could look like this:

```cs
// setup the connection to the remote endpoint
// and start the data flow
using var connection = new TcpClient(_connectionInfo.Name, _connectionInfo.Port) {
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Milliseconds,
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Milliseconds,
};
...
// now use a SocketConnection to suck the data out
var reader = SocketConnection.Create(connection.Client/*aka Socket*/).Input;
while (!_stopToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
  if (reader.TryRead(out ReadResult result)) {
    ...
    ...
    reader.AdvanceTo(result.Buffer.End);
  }else {
      _stopToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  }
}
```

Don't forget to either advance your reader or cancel it with `CancelPendingRead()`, otherwise, the next call will throw with "Read already in progress".
Note that if you want to *write* data eventually, you have to flush it, and there is no synchronous Flush available, which is another reason I do not recommend this.